# Is @ngrx/store a hot or cold observable?

Tags: observable, ngrx

I think that it is a cold observable (as is the default) but couldn't find a reference to it either in the code or the documentation.

(Sorry if this is asked already, couldn't find something)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**;TLDR** It's a hot observable because both [ActionSubject](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/store/src/actions_subject.ts) and [ReducerManager](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/store/src/reducer_manager.ts) extend [BehaviorSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject) which is a hot observable.

As stated in the diagram at https://ngrx.io/guide/store
[image: Ngrx state management lifecycle]

The store receives events from Actions, and Actions are processed via Reducers.
Both ActionSubject (the observable of actions) and ReducerManager (the observable of reducer) inherit BehaviorSubject from RxJs library.

The docs and source code are taken from ngrx/store 4.x https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/modules/store/src

Hope that help.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I intuited that store was a hot observable, since the events were being emitted no matter that no component was subscribed to them, but I didn't know anything about ActionSubject and ReducerManager.