# NgRx Selector - cold or hot observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I know that the ngrx store is a hot observable based on this answer: [Is @ngrx/store a hot or cold observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54629140/is-ngrx-store-a-hot-or-cold-observable)

My question is if a selector is a hot or cold observable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's cold because it won't subscribe to the source until someone subscribes to it.

Most operators except for the `share` and `publish` operators create cold observables.

Answer (score 3):

Selectors are pure functions not observables.

You're probably asking about the [`select`](https://ngrx.io/api/store/select) operator or function.

```ts
this.store.pipe(select(...)) // or this.store.select(...)
```

That's basically just

```ts
this.store.pipe(
  map(...),
  distinctUntilChanged()
)
```

`map` and `distinctUntilChanged` don't really make an observable hot or cold. They only subscribe to their source if they are subscribed to, so data will only flow through them if you subscribe. But if the source (e.g. store) receives items from producers before you subscribe (i.e. is hot) you won't receive them.

So subscribing to `this.store.pipe(select(...))` won't tell the store to start producing values, the store will emit values before that as it's actively listening to its producers (reducers & actions), but `select` won't listen to the store and no data will flow through it unless you subscribe.